# Bug when printing <iframe> in Google Chrome 35

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So, I'm getting complains from my users that the print feature of our website is not working anymore. After some investigation, I found out this is a problem specific to the recent version of Chrome (number 35, released May 20th 2014). So the traditional code

```
window.frames[ "my-iframe" ].focus( )
window.frames[ "my-iframe" ].print( )
```

is now broken in Google's browser. The error is:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Other people are having similar problems ([here](http://imacros.net/chrome-35-update-breaks-imacros-chrome) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/778000/Print-iframe-at-Chrome)).

It looks like window.frames[ "my-iframe" ] is returning a `frameElement` instead of the DOM object.

Any solution or workaround to fix this print issue just for Chrome?

Comment: frames[ "my-iframe" ] should return window

Comment: Random fact I just discovered: `window.frames === window`.

Comment: I am confused ... I just tried to add a named iframe to my page DOM using Chrome 35, and `print` and `focus` are working just fine. I don't get any error and print preview page is showing fine.

Comment: I tested this in Windows and OS X. Same problem. My iframe has an id and shows a PDF (not sure if that matters).

Comment: Can’t reproduce in Chrome version `35.0.1916.114 m` on Win 7 – both `window.frames["framename"]` and `window.framename` still report as a `Window` instance when logged to console, and calling print method on them works fine.

Comment: Please be precise! Your iframe has an `id` or a `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, guys! My bad. I was using "id" instead of "name" inside the iframe. Safari was understanding it anyway, as well as previous versions of Chrome.

Simple solution, apparently.

Comment: Had the same problem. Make sure your iframe has a NAME and reference that with window.frame["my-iframe-NAME"].print()